# How to minimize $(p_1^2 + (1-p_1)^2)^n$ where $p_1 = 1-(1-(k/n))^N$

Tags: calculus, optimization

Consider  $S_{n,N,k} = (p_1^2 + (1-p_1)^2)^n$ where $p_1 = 1-(1-(k/n))^N$.  If we fix $N$ and $n$, how do we find a $k$ which minimizes $S_{n,N,k}$?

We assume that $1 \leq k <  N$ if that makes a difference and both $n$ and $N$ are large.

Comment: I can answer soon when I'm on a computer. However if you know what I'm talking about, just take the partial of $S $ with respect to $k $ and set it to $0$ then solve for $k $. Then just check to make sure it's a minimum not a maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For easier differentiation I will write
$$S_{n,N,k}=(2p_1^2-2p_1+1)^n$$
Taking the partial with respect to $k$ we get
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial S}{\partial k} &=n\left(2p_1^2-2p_1+1\right)^{n-1}\left(4p_1\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial k}-2\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial k}\right) \\
&= nN(1-k/n)^{N-1}\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(2p_1^2-2p_1+1\right)^{n-1}(4p_1-2) \\
&= -2N(1-k/n)^{N-1}\left(2p_1^2-2p_1+1\right)^{n-1}(2p_1-1)
\end{align}$$
Setting this to $0$ we have
$$\begin{align}
0 &=(1-k/n)^{N-1}\left(2p_1^2-2p_1+1\right)^{n-1}(2p_1-1) \\
&= (1-k/n)^{N-1}(1-k/n)^{2N(n-1)}(1-2(1-k/n)^{N}) \\
&= (1-k/n)^{2Nn-N-1}(1-2(1-k/n)^N)
\end{align}$$
Which is of course the case when $k_1=n$ and $k_2=n-n/\sqrt[N]{2}$. Computing $S$ at these values we have
$$\begin{align}
S_{n,N,k_1} &=1 \\
S_{n,N,k_2} &=2^{-n}
\end{align}$$
We also check the boundaries, and nothing special occurs. (I am going to assume this is a minimum value not a local maximum, you can check that). Hence the minimizing value for $k$ is
$$k=n-n/\sqrt[N]{2}$$

Comment: The answer is surprisingly lovely!

Comment: Yep, I was surprised as well. Where'd this problem come from?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867646/probability-two-vectors-creating-by-repeated-logical-ors-are-the-same?noredirect=1#comment3825731_1867646  :) It seems that $p_1 = 1/2$ is optimal just from plugging in your value for $k$ and you get $S_{n,N,k} = 1/2^n$ which is even more pleasing.

Comment: As I also need that $k \geq 1$ which means that $n\geq  1/(1-2^{-1/N})$ and so $n \geq N/\ln{2}$ plus some small terms.

Comment: You may want to do a more thorough evaluation of the bounds if you want. Like check what happens to $S$ as $k$ approaches $1$ and as it approaches $N$.